# Cordova/Phonegap Media Plugin Next/Previous Button

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I am using Cordova media plugin to play music. All works fine. When I lock the screen I see the default music player playing music. But when I press the next or previous track button nothing happens.

Is there a way to listen to the next/previous track button events? I have highlighted the buttons on the below image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but I think the RemoteControls plugin will help you:

https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls

You can listen `remote-event` like this and decide what to do:

```
document.addEventListener("remote-event", function(event) {
   //do something
})
```

Don't forget to set this event listener **after** importing `cordova.js` and setting `deviceready` event.

```
<script src="./cordova.js"></script>
<script>
   document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(event) {
      document.addEventListener("remote-event", function(event) {
        // see what happens in event
        // console.log(event)
        // and do something
      })
   })
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing it. For now I am upvoting it. Once I try it I will check it as answer.

Comment: I hope it helps, let me know the result :)